# Cant remove Debug Show Checked Banner

Tags: flutter, dart

I used the `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,` code to remove the debug banner and it had worked fine with all of my previous apps. But now when I used this code only the shadow under debug banner get removed.
Here's my code

```
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

I have attached the images link of `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,` and `debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,`below.

How can I remove this debug banner completely, please help!

Comment: Please share the code of HomeScreen().

Comment: When ```debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true```
https://imgur.com/a/k0DiKaC

When ```debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false```
https://imgur.com/a/sVGGfO6

Comment: What I want is the code for HomeScreen() , not the image.

Comment: There might be a `Banner` widget in HomeScreen, check your code

Comment: This are the code of HomeScreen:

```class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('E Com App'),),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Text( 'Red Container',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),),),),); }}```

Comment: @Kavin-K There isn't any.

Comment: @MyCar I have added the codes for HomeScreen.

Comment: Please, when updating details, edit your original question and don't do it over the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you.

Remove `MaterialApp` Widget from `HomeScreen` Class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: HomeScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('E Com App'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        height: 200,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Text(
          'Red Container',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Your Result Screen-> [image]

If you want `MaterialApp` Widget in `HomeScreen` class then add below line inside `MaterialApp` in `HomeScreen Class`.

```
 debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
```

Full Widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: HomeScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('E Com App'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Text(
            'Red Container',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, Happy to help you .

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
//this code add it 
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: HomeScreen(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: It was already imported. Anyway, I got the solution in the upper comment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).